# tmp_name not holding my uploaded file

Tags: php

I am trying to run a php script to upload an image to a location on my server while storing its the location details in my database.

All seems fine except my tmp_name doesn't seem to be getting the file so all I get is the string location in the database pointing to a file not existing in my server. I couldn't figure out this one.

First this is the html markup:

```
$imgsize=$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$location = 'db/farmers_pPix/';
$load_dataFarmerPix="form/".$location.$FNAME.'_'.$LNAME.'_'.$FNO.'-'.$name;
$passport=$load_dataFarmerPix;
...
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    if (!empty($name)) {
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $load_dataFarmerPix);
        if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $load_dataFarmerPix)){
            echo '<p style="width:100%; color:#777; font-family:eurof35-webfont;"><h4 class="text-center">Your profle has been created and photo Uploaded</h4></p>';
        }

    } else {
        echo '<p style="width:100%; color:#777; font-family:eurof35-webfont;text-align:center;" class="text-center"><h5>please choose a file</h5></p>';
    }
    echo '<p style="width:100%; color:#777; font-family:eurof55-webfont;text-align:center;"><h3 class="text-center">Registration Successfull</h3></p>';
 }  
}
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" style="color:#ccc;" action="farmreg2.php" method="post">
...
    <li>
<label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q5">Upload a Current Photo?    </label>
<input class="fs-anim-lower" style="color:#ccc; padding:1%;" id="id"  name="file" type="file" placeholder="Supported formats (jpg,png,bmp,gif)"/>
<input class="fs-anim-lower" id="id" value="30000"  name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" placeholder="" required/>
</li>
...
</form>
```

this file itself is farmreg2.php

Comment: you run `move_uploaded_file` twice

Comment: echoing the tmp_name i get /tmp/phpE3adVe

Comment: i jst remove one, still the same result

Comment: there is no db adding in the script, the variable that you should be storeing in the db is: `$load_dataFarmerPix`

Comment: ddnt add d db in d script but how do i check if my files are actually getting to the tmp_name / temporary location

Comment: `$x=move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $load_dataFarmerPix); if($x){//file moved worked}`

Comment: tried that php just skips it 2 show its nt uploading